# TypeScript generics: circular or self-bound type variables possible?

Tags: generics, typescript

TypeScript does not seems to allow `?` wildcard in generic type instantiations nor does it allow referring to the type variable itself, so how could the following examples be correctly written?

```
class Collection<I extends Item<Collection<I>>> {
}

class Item<C extends Collection<Item<C>>> {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be coming in 1.5 or 1.6.  They just merged in a bunch of PRs for circular references.  For example: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2823